# Access a variable on a controller on two seperate visualforce pages

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

I have two visual force pages that use the same controller. There a few fields which I set on the first visual page which I would like to access on the second visualforce page. I was wondering how I could accomplish this?

Here is what I currently have in my controller:

```
// most functions have been removed. 
public with sharing class someController{

    //standard controller declarations
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}

    public String identifier {get;set;} //This is the field I want to access on both pages


     /**
     * Constructor
     **/
    public DeviceLookupController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        this.controller = controller;

    }
}
```

Essentially, I want the `identifier` field to be available on two visualforce pages from the `someController`.

The `someController` that is shown above is an extension to both pages, and the `standardController` is set as the same object on both pages.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar is implemented in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm?search_text=wizard).

You man want to have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

AlvinJ,

I see that you are using Same standard controller and extension in both the pages. It seems they have, more likely, similar functionalities. Following are the options i could suggest from the given information:

1. Merge VF pages :  Use Boolean variable for conditional render of VF components

```html
<apex:pageBlockSection id="xxxpbs1" rendered="{!ShowPage1}">

</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection id="xxxpbs2" rendered="{!ShowPage2}">
                                                                     
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

2. Query string : If you have just one or two identifiers and security is not a concern then please pass the identifier variable via query string. Please find below a link to an example of query string 
   [Getting Query String Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_query_params_getting.htm)

Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks